AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'submit'
I am using fastapi and uvicorn as my python server and whenever a user visits a route, I want to start a subprocess in the background. I used asyncio.create_task and loop.run_in_excutor in order to properly handle the subprocess code.
PYTHON VERSION :- 3.11.3
OPERATING SYSTEM :- Windows x64
@router.get("/testdo")
async def do():
    asyncio.create_task(editing())
    
    # Return a response immediately
    return {"message": "Video processing started in the background!"}

async def editing():
    recordingFile = os.path.join(temp_dir, f"test.mp4")
    webFile = os.path.join(temp_dir, f"keeptest.mp4")
    ffmpeg_change_bitrate = ['ffmpeg', '-i', recordingFile, '-b:v', '5M', '-y', f'{webFile}']
    
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    process = await loop.run_in_executor(subprocess.run, ffmpeg_change_bitrate)
    
    stdout, stderr = await process.communicate()
    
    if process.returncode == 0:
        print('Completed Editing')
    else:
        print(f'Error occurred: {stderr.decode()}')
    print('It will take more x seconds')
    await asyncio.sleep(20)  # Simulate additional processing time for POST request to S3 bucket
    print('It took x seconds')
    
    print('Completed Editing, it took x minutes')


I am getting the following error :-
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-5' coro=<editing() done, defined at C:\Users\Zaid Ahmed\Desktop\LatestProject\Phia-Backend\src\routes\render.py:26> exception=AttributeError("'function' object has no attribute 'submit'")>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Zaid Ahmed\Desktop\LatestProject\Phia-Backend\src\routes\render.py", line 37, in editing
    process = await loop.run_in_executor(subprocess.run, ffmpeg_change_bitrate)
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Zaid Ahmed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 829, in run_in_executor
    executor.submit(func, *args), loop=self)
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'submit'


https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/background-tasks/ might be a better way to offload a task like that

@Will The background task would create a task, but the subprocess.run blocks every other requests on the server. If I try to visit any route on the server during the subprocess running ffmpeg, it won't load until the subprocess is completed

@Zaid background tasks doesn't replace the executer, it just makes sure your request handler doesn't tear down while your subprocess is still running, allowing you to return response early. If everything blocks it might have to do with running a non async workload in an async handler

You forgot to specify executor in run_in_executor method in this line:
process = await loop.run_in_executor(subprocess.run, ffmpeg_change_bitrate)

run_in_executor has this specification: awaitable loop.run_in_executor(executor, func, *args)
You passed func as first argument, but you need executor to come first, func should be second, and then *args
You can check function semantics and example in Documentation
The correct code should look something like that (I didn't test it, just a suggestion):
with ThreadPoolExecutor() as pool: # or maybe ProcessPoolExecutor
    process = await loop.run_in_executor(pool, subprocess.run, ffmpeg_change_bitrate)

